# PHP setcookie() function not working in Wordpress Template File

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

I am using this code to set a cookie in a wordpress site. When I place this code in header.php, it works perfectly. But when I place this code in Separate template file, it does not work.
Header File Code: (Before HTML Tag)

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['City'])) {
setcookie('City', 0, -(3600*3600*3600));
setcookie('City', "Edmonton2", 3600*3600*3600);
}
else {
setcookie('City', "Edmonton", 3600*3600*3600);
}
```

WP Template File Code: (Code is before the get_header() function)

```
<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE['City'])) {
setcookie('City', 0, -(3600*3600*3600));
setcookie('City', "Edmonton2", 3600*3600*3600);
}
else {
setcookie('City', "Edmonton", 3600*3600*3600);
}
?>
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Community Landing Page
*/
get_header(); ?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was I did not mention the path in the function. The code was creating cookie for the particular page. Here is the corrected function:

```
setcookie('City', "Edmonton43003", (time()+3600), "/");
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't set a cookie after output has started. Cookies and all other HTTP header information can only be set before the output has started. **Output** can mean anything from an empty space before PHP tags to actual HTML content.

You shouldn't ever have to put cookies in a body. All logic should be done before starting output of templates.

Comment: I have added the code in header.php before HTML tag and its working. In template file, I have added it before calling the get_header() function. I have also tried by removing the get_header() function and then hardcode the started HTML tag and put the code before that, but that did not work too.

Comment: Replace the code with `echo "blah blah blah";` if that echo isnt the first thing seen when viewing the source it will not work and you need to re arrange the code

Comment: Just checked, It is the first thing on the page.
Also checked by placing echo "checking" in header.php and got "blah blah checking" as output. As echo "blah blah" is in template file.

Comment: In Wordpress this can often be the case, plugin scripts have random white space at the end of them which needs to be removed. By default Wordpress supresses errors telling you where to look so add this before the code you want to debug to get some clues: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);`